# Getting Data from Android Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I have seen some Apps and Websites who use Data from the Android Play store. E.g. Apps or Sites with a top Apps ranking etc. But how can you get the Data? From where I can parse it?

Comment: There are open Q&As on the OpenData site: [here](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/5311/1511) and [here](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/4271/1511) and [here](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/4638/1511)

Comment: @Umair no thanks. this question is more than 5 years old.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There's an unofficial [open-source API for the Android Market](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/) you may try to use to get the information you need. Hope this helps.

Comment: What is "ANDROID_DEVICEID" in local.php?

Answer (score 25):

I've coded a small Node.js module to scrape app and list data from Google Play: [google-play-scraper](https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper)

```
var gplay = require('google-play-scrapper');

gplay.List({
    category: gplay.category.GAME_ACTION,
    collection: gplay.collection.TOP_FREE,
    num: 2
  }).then(console.log);
```

Results:

```
 [ { url: 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.playappking.busrush',
    appId: 'com.playappking.busrush',
    title: 'Bus Rush',
    developer: 'Play App King',
    icon: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/R6hmyJ6ls6wskk5hHFoW02yEyJpSG36il4JBkVf-Aojb1q4ZJ9nrGsx6lwsRtnTqfA=w340',
    score: 3.9,
    price: '0',
    free: false },
  { url: 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yodo1.crossyroad',
    appId: 'com.yodo1.crossyroad',
    title: 'Crossy Road',
    developer: 'Yodo1 Games',
    icon: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/doHqbSPNekdR694M-4rAu9P2B3V6ivff76fqItheZGJiN4NBw6TrxhIxCEpqgO3jKVg=w340',
    score: 4.5,
    price: '0',
    free: false } ]
```

Comment: I guess so, this is all publicly available data. It would be funny google saying "hey don't you crawl my site".

Comment: This is a Node.js package. You can build a simple node app to dump this to a database, or you can bundle it with browserify to run it from the browser. You can also use [this wrapper](https://github.com/facundoolano/gps-webtask) I wrote if you want to expose it as a RESTful API.

Comment: 2016 Update: this module isn't small anymore, now it covers pretty much every aspect of the store: app detail, collections, search, apps by developer, reviews, similar apps and search suggestions.

Comment: thanks man, I was looking for a tool like this. I actually wanted to get the reviews of a third party app whose play developer console access I don't have and the API by google are asking for access token. I would love to know the underlying architecture  of the node module, how does it fetches the review from play store ?

Comment: All the data is taken either directly from the exposed html or using the underlying APIs that Google Play calls. In the case of the reviews, the data comes from the API that is called when you browse the reviews in the app listing page.

Comment: I also found a promising project on github https://github.com/s101d1/CSPlayStoreScraper .

Answer (score 23):

Disclaimer: I am from 42matters, who provides this data already on https://42matters.com/api , feel free to check it out or drop us a line.

As lenik mentioned there are open-source libraries that already help with obtaining some data from GPlay. If you want to build one yourself you can try to parse the Google Play App page, but you should pay attention to the following:

- Make sure the URL you are trying to parse is not blocked in robots.txt - e.g. https://play.google.com/robots.txt
- Make sure that you are not doing it too often, Google will throttle and potentially blacklist you if you are doing it too much.
- Send a correct User-Agent header to actually show you are a bot
- The page of an app is big - make sure you accept gzip and request the mobile version
- GPlay website is not an API, it doesn't care that you parse it so it will change over time. Make sure you handle changes - e.g. by having test to make sure you get what you expected.

So that in mind getting one page metadata is a matter of fetching the page html and parsing it properly. With [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) you can try:

```
      HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
      HttpGet request = new HttpGet(crawlUrl);
      HttpResponse rsp = httpClient.execute(request);

      int statusCode = rsp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

      if (statusCode == 200) {
           String content = EntityUtils.toString(rsp.getEntity());    
           Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);
           //parse content, whatever you need
           Element price = doc.select("[itemprop=price]").first();
      }
```

For that very simple use case that should get you started. However, the moment you want to do more interesting stuff, things get complicated:

- Search is forbidden in robots.
- Keeping app metadata up-to-date is hard to do. There are more than 2.2m apps, if you want to refresh their metadata daily there are 2.2 requests/day, which will 1) get blocked immediately, 2) costs a lot of money - pessimistic 220gb data transfer per day if one app is 100k
- How do you discover new apps
- How do you get pricing in each country, translations of each language

The list goes on. If you don't want to do all this by yourself, you can consider [42matters API](https://42matters.com/api), which supports lookup and search, top google charts, advanced queries and filters. And this for 35 languages and more than 50 countries.

[2]:

Comment: Fetching user reviews is not currently supported by the 42matters API (which is otherwise quite nice). Hopefully this will save someone from creating and then abandoning an account.

Comment: **This service is very expensive**

Comment: How do you get "User also likes" data for your api? Cooperating with Google?Because it´s impossible to get that by crawling the market...

Comment: Your website - 42matters is giving a 503 :(

Answer (score 5):

The Google Play Store doesn't provide this data, so the sites must just be scraping it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a google chrome extension that'll allow you to download **your** reviews: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/my-play-store-reviews/ldggikfajgoedghjnflfafiiheagngoa?hl=en