# web crawl the app information from Android market

Tags: android, web, web-crawler

I want to get a dataset of Android application information, which includes application name, package name, version, permission requested, etc.

The official Android application market is Google Play.  There are millions of applications on the market.  I want to get at least tens of thousands of application information from it, and store it into a csv file.  For instance, here's an application's link:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.ralphsapps.snorecontrol

- The problem is how to get the list of applications' url?
- How to to parse the information from webpage?

Is there any good web crawler suitable for this kind of job?  Or is there any scripting language, such as python, has such kind of crawl functions?

Thanks.

Comment: try an [api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272155/getting-data-from-android-play-store). If it does not do what you need, maybe contribute back a patch?

Comment: Thanks so much. Your information is useful!

Comment: @babysnow got the same problem. how did you overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Google Play Store` has its own format to display information objects in HTML.
Write your own HTML parser for all these to get information you need.

It's best to use **JSoup** for this job at [JSoup.org](http://jsoup.org) ,

or refer to my sample tutorial on `JSoup` as a parser: 
 [Parsing HTML using JSoup](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2012/02/04/android-xml-adventure-parsing-html-using-jsoup/)

Comment: grab all urls on the index page of each category

Comment: I found Python also has HTMLParser.  I kind of prefer the Python one, because script is easier to write. Java library seems need more efforts.