# Google Play scraper

Tags: php, http, post, goutte

I'm trying to develop a Play Store reviews scraper in PHP and I need to make a POST request to this URL `https://play.google.com/store/getreviews`, and I saw the parameter post with firebug.

I am using [Goutte library](https://github.com/fabpot/goutte) and here is my code:

```
require_once 'goutte.phar';
use Goutte\Client;    

$client = new Client();

$params = Array(
    "id"      => "com.trello",
    "pageNum" => 2         ,
    "reviewSortOrder" => 2 ,
    "reviewType"   => 0,
    "xhr" => 1
);

$crawler = $client->request('POST' , 'https://play.google.com/store/getreviews', $params);
```

The problem is that the request returns nothing. Is there anyone who already faced this problem and solved it?

Comment: Sometimes websites will block certain user agents. Have you tried sending a fake user-agent string (e.g. one copied from firebug) along with your POST?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Data from Android Play Store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272155/getting-data-from-android-play-store)

Comment: Show us the full request that works, and show us the full request that doesn't.  Use a tool like Fiddler or Wireshark.

Comment: if you need another library (which is really good), you can use Zend_Http_Client http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.http.client.advanced.html

Comment: @maxton i tried right click on the post request from firebug and copy as cURL, if it's what you mean.

Comment: @krab thank you, l'll check  it out!

Comment: @brad i'm on mobile phone right now. i'll provide the full requests as soon as i can

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. Google Play changed their review interface last year. They now have a "token" parameter which is missing here. I have worked before to try and work out what seeds this (see [Google play review scraping changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18482660/google-play-review-scraping-changes)) but I can't figure it out. After a number of attempts to hit that webservice with an incorrect request (presumably without the token) Google Play starts blocking your IP, that's why you'll be getting nothing back after a while (and won't be able to open Google Play in your browser either). If you find a solution, let me know!

Answer (score 1):

This URL works for me, with the form-post data in your example.

```
https://play.google.com/store/getreviews?authuser=0
```