# How do I get my app information from Google Play using PHP?

Tags: php, web-services, api, google-play

I have been doing some R&D on this but just can't seem to get enough information, I know we can get basic app information from Google Play using some API, because i have used 42matters Google Market API to get my app information.

How can I as a developer directly interact with Google Play to get basic app information like app title, name, size, developer, price etc using package name without the help of API and develop my own API which gives my desired result set?

Comment: I have read that, most of the answers are about the same API i mentioned above which i dont want to use and the correct answer is for android development not web specifically PHP, so this is not the duplicate and not what i asked in the question

Comment: dont mark it duplicate to the question above my question is totally different, i want to know how those api can get information and not developers like us

Comment: Do the answers given in that question not give you the basic information you are after? What data are you after that, for example, 42Matters does not give you? (If you believe this is not a duplicate, you need to show why).

Comment: There are answers in that question (and comments on those answers) which describe where those APIs get their data from.

Comment: as i mentioned i want to know how api's like 42matter get that data from google play store, moreover, 42matter api is not commercially free and i want to post the info i get on my website, like name, price, screenshot, icon etc..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10272223/19068

Comment: i know something called scrapping i used, but 2 out of three links to scraping point to JSOUP, and that is java based, i dont know anything about java

Comment: thanx @Quentin this is really useful, just reading it now...
write it in an answer so ican mark it if i get what i want

Comment: Scraping just means "Parsing the data out of the HTML web pages".

Comment: Ah yes, 42Matters requires a fee. Why not get in touch with them? If your purpose is commercial, it may be cheaper to pay the fee than to develop a scraper yourself. That said, you could use something like Import.io which has a free tier for certain levels of scraping - they have desktop tools to design scrapers.

Comment: @blogger — It's already an answer on the duplicate question!

Comment: thanx everybody here got info which i was looking for...

Comment: @blogger I am from 42matters, please contact us and I will be happy to help with our API if you still need support!