# How to Get the Information about android application from google play store programatically

Tags: android

My project requirement is to categorize the installed application in android device
 like games, communication, social, news, lifestyle....
To do this i need to get the details about the application.. so please suggest me..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Data from Android Play Store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272155/getting-data-from-android-play-store)

Comment: You can go through this link https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/libraries, https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/ or https://github.com/chadrem/market_bot