# Getting/updating Rating from/to Google Play store

Tags: javascript, google-play, rating

I have one android application in the Google play store. I just wanted know whether I can show the current rating of the App in my Website, if its possible or not. Is there any sort of JavaScript API ?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/ ## http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272155/getting-data-from-android-play-store

Comment: Is there anything available for Javascript ?

Comment: Please refer to the links I provided there is a answer there about 42matters api. A web api can be used by any HTTP request capable language.