# Google Play Store API for Application Download & Uninstall Count + Application Rating

Tags: android, ios, google-play, google-play-services

I have any Requirement to show the Number of **Downloads** + **Number of Uninstall** + **User Rating of Application** from Google Play Store and iOS.
Is there any API available wherein I can Fetch this information and show it in another application.

Answer (score 3):

Google Play now allows to access your own app "Download reports" programmatically via **Google Cloud Storage** and **gutils** as explained here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?hl=en

For iOS you can access reports for your own app via the **App Store Connect API**, for example with this endpoint: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/download_sales_and_trends_reports

However, if you want to access data about third-party apps (e.g. to build a competitors analysis report) you would need non-Google and non-Apple alternatives that can provide you with "Download estimates" (i.e. calculated based on statistical models), historical rating data, etc. You can have a look at the [Lookup API for Android Apps](https://42matters.com/docs/app-market-data/android/apps/lookup?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=Referral&utm_campaign=37594984), which provides a lot of of apps' information that can be used for bulging your app-tracking dashboard.

(Full disclosure: I am the CEO at 42matters.com)

Comment: This answer is misleading, There is no such API Google or Apple provides at the moment. gutil is python library and sales & trends API doesn't provide uninstall count.

Comment: Please provide sample request and response if you still think that API is available.

Answer (score 1):

Google Play Store API doesn't seem to mention any of the features you've stated. Google Play Developer API is used to manage:

1. In-App Products (in-app products and subscriptions catalog management)
2. Products purchase status
3. Subscriptions purchase management

The closest thing I can suggest is that you check the [new Firebase 2.0](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485). They've added better analytics centered on mobile apps.

Check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272155/getting-data-from-android-play-store) for other non-Google alternatives. There's also a bunch of non-Google software to track uninstalls [suggested by Quora users](https://www.quora.com/How-to-track-android-or-ios-app-uninstalls).