# List the all android aps based on the developer

Tags: android, google-play

i want to show the all android apps based on the developer. For this requirement i have searched allot but i didn't get any solution. Any one had idea about this....

**Explanation:**

Suppose one company submitted some apps in google play store then these apps have to be list in my activity. If this company submits any apps in future also those have to be list in my activity

**Edit**

When clicking on each app we have to redirect the user to play store for downloading the particular app

Answer (score 0):

**An open-source API for the Android Market**

> This is not an official API.

This library allow you to ask directly google's official android market servers for information, search for apps, ...

**Requirement**

No specific requirement, it use java.net.URL for communication with the google market server.

**Current Progress/Features**

1. You can browse market with any carrier or locale you want.
2. Search for apps using keywords or package name.
3. Retrieve an app info using an app ID.
4. Retrieve comments using an app ID.
5. Get PNG screenshots and icon.

Reference: https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-market-api/

For any help using this API please use the [Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/android-market-api).

You can also find some useful answers in this question.
[Getting Data from Android Play Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272155/getting-data-from-android-play-store)

Comment: Hi as you said i have used this jar https://www.dropbox.com/s/umnkuyvisvnv2vm/AndroidMarketApi-20151023.jar and fallowed the code like https://www.dropbox.com/s/e29cr9qjgzui87p/TechApps.java but it's not executing the session.append(appsRequest.... method. Can you help in this?

Comment: @Bahu check [this issues](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-market-api/issues) if didn't find anything specific ask same on this  [Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/android-market-api)